# Why are Gold codes and Kasami codes used instead of pure m-sequences?

Tags: digital-communications, spread-spectrum

I'm trying to understand why Gold codes and Kasami codes are used instead of pure m-sequences, in direct-sequence spread-spectrum (DSSS) communication systems, to prevent interference between multiple transmitters.

If I understand correctly, Gold codes are defined as the XOR between two m-sequences with different polynomials of the same degree (e.g. one LFSRs based on $p_1(x)$, and another LFSR based on $p_2(x)$ both of degree 20; the LFSR outputs are then XOR'd together), and within one system, multiple transmitters use the same pairs of polynomials but with a different time shift. (Kasami is also an XOR so I guess it's similar.)

How is this better than, say, having a system where all transmitters use m-sequences but each of them uses a different polynomial? (In both cases, the autocorrelation values are higher than the cross-correlation values)

Comment: because the XOR and shift register stuffs are fast.

Comment: both are fast, but why are Gold/Kasami better?

Comment: Activate and Accesses Processes into the Google Data Kasamai!Thank You!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are very few *m*-sequences of any given length with *good* cross-correlation properties.  Their *autocorrelation* properties are excellent, but the cross-correlation properties are variable.  For example, there are 18 *m*-sequences of period 127 but to have good cross-correlation properties, one must choose a set of no more than $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{3}}$ 6 *m*-sequences out of the 18 available. As a consequence, when several sequences with good cross-correlation properties are needed, one needs to use Gold sequence sets  or Kasami sequence sets which have good cross-correlation properties *and* good (though not excellent) autocorrelation properties.

For more than you probably want to know, I refer you to the paper D.V. Sarwate and M.B. Pursley, "Cross-correlation properties of pseudorandom and related sequences," Proc. IEEE, vol.68, pp.593-619, May 1980. It includes a detailed discussion of the Gold sequences as well as the small sets and large sets of Kasami sequences.

Comment: huh... what happens if you have 4 m-sequences? they have good pairwise cross-correlation properties, but .... ?

Comment: I had typos in. my answer. At length 127, the cross-correlation between two _m_-sequences must have value at least 17. If you _choose_ 6  _m_-sequences carefully (i.e. not a random selection), the $15 = \binom{6}{2}$ cross-correlations all have maximum value 17. If you add a 7th _m_-sequence into the set _and it doesn't matter which the seventh one is_, the new sequence will have cross-correlation _at least_ 41 with one of the original 6 sequences. At longer lengths (up to $2^{15}-1$) there are only smaller subsets of _m_-sequences that will work, See Table 1 of my paper cited above.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the mutually acceptable m-sequences are hard to construct (need very particular subsets of m-sequences with a given length), whereas with Gold sequences they are easy and systematic to construct.

Comment: are those pairs of m-sequences which have low cross-correlation the same thing as the "preferred pairs" found in your paper + others?

Comment: Yes, and the sets of sequences in which _each_ pair is a preferred pair is called a connected set. 6 is the size of the _maximal_ connected set of length 127.

Comment: I have a related question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44920/computing-the-decimation-ratio-between-two-m-sequences that I was wondering if you could look at.